# Get contact groups names by contact-id in a single query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts, contactscontract

I known how retrieve the group ids at that belongs a contact

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
    }, 
    String.format("%s=? AND %s=?", ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE), 
    new String[] { 
        Long.toString(contact_id),
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE 
    }, null);
```

and also how obtain the group name if I known the id.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
    }, 
    String.format("%s=?", ContactsContract.Groups._ID), 
    new String[] { Long.toString(id) }, 
    null);
```

But is possible to obtains the group names at that belongs a contact (by id) in a single query?